# NameError: name 'board1' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def initialize_board():

    board1 = ['*', '*', '*']
    board2 = ['*', '*', '*']
    board3 = ['*', '*', '*']

    print(board1)
    print(board2)
    print(board3)

    return board1
    return board2
    return board3
```

So I initialized my board for tic-tac-toe in this first function

And then I have this function:

```
import random

def input_choice():

    initialize_board()


    player_1 = input('What is your name?')
    player_2 = input('What is your name?')

    #See who goes first

    player_1_choice = input('Choose heads or tales')
    player_2_choice = input('Choose head or tales')

    if random.choice(['heads', 'tales']) == player_1_choice:
        print(f'{player_1} goes first!')
    else:
        print(f'{player_2} goes first1')

    placements = {1 : board1[0], 2 : board1[1], 3 : board1[2], 4 : board2[0], 5 : board2[1], 6 : board2[2], 7 : board3[0], 8 : board3[1], 9: board3[2]}

    print(board1)
```

However I get an error saying that board1 is not defined when its been defined in the first function.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-dd18b3b6beab> in <module>
----> 1 input_choice()

<ipython-input-29-1ebcf8044e68> in input_choice()
     19         print(f'{player_2} goes first1')
     20 
---> 21     placements = {1 : board1[0], 2 : board1[1], 3 : board1[2], 4 : board2[0], 5 : board2[1], 6 : board2[2], 7 : board3[0], 8 : board3[1], 9: board3[2]}
     22 
     23     print(board1)
NameError: name 'board1' is not defined
```

Comment: Variables in functions have scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules. Furthermore, you can't simultaneously return multiple values from a function by using multiple return statements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to have a descriptive title. Also read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: There are a couple of flaws in your code. The actual error comes from the fact that `board1` is only defined within your function `initialize_board()` and the variable is local. Additionally you cannot have multiple return statements within one function.

Comment: And, with the above, you never assign the output of `initialize_board()` to anything so the variable returned doesn't exist

Comment: Use return board1, board2, board3 in initialize_board.  And have board1, board2, board3 = initialize_board().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define two different functions, their local variables exist in different scopes. So the local variables inside `initialize_board()` are not visible to the function `input_choice()` until you return any of those values.

Another thing to note is that when you reach the first return statement in `initialize_board()`, i.e. when you reach `return board_1`, the function literally **returns** control to the point from where it was called. So you never actually reach the other two return statements.

How can you fix this?

Return all the three variables in one statement like this:

```py
def initialize_board(): 
    # your code
    return board_1, board_2, board_3
```

And now in the caller function, **assign these returned values** to some other variables that are local to `input_choice()` function.

```py
def input_choice():

    # these variables do not have to have the same name as the variables being returned.
    # So b1, b2, b3 = initialize_board() is also a valid statement
    # these variables are local to this function
    board_1, board_2, board_3 = initialize_board()
    ...
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `initialize_board` function isn't returning the board correctly, and your `input_choice` function isn't looking at the return value.  There is no value for `board1` within the body of `input_choice`, which is why you get an error when you try to access it.

Change your `initialize_board` to return all three rows:

```
return board1, board2, board3
```

and then in `input_choice` make sure you actually retrieve those values when you call `initialize_board`:

```
board1, board2, board3 = initialize_board()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

board1 is a variable that is scoped to your initialize_board function. You'll need to set the return of initialize_board in input_choice to a variable and use that. You also won't be able to return on three separate lines like that in initialize_board. Maybe put those three lists into a dictionary and return that in your initialize_board function.

Comment: Since they're ordered, a tuple is perfectly reasonable instead of a dict: `return board1, board2, board3`

Comment: Really appreciate the help, thanks for sorting my problem.